# TeamCity only publishing 1 package to NuGet feed when it should be publishing 4

Tags: nuget, teamcity

We have a build configuration that contains four NuGet Pack build steps.  Each step creates a nuget package as an artifact, in which each package should get published to the nuget feed hosted by TeamCity.

For up to 59 versions of these files, this has worked fine, however suddenly, on the 60th build, its now only publishing 1 of the 4 packages.

Below is a screenshot of the 'Nuget Packages' tab on the latest succesful build:

[image]

Unfortunately the build history only shows the latest 5 builds, so I'm unable to show the result of the build that did produce the 4 packages.

Below is a partial of the build log for the build configuration - it contains the log for the package that does get published and another for one that doesn't:

```
[16:23:35]  Step 3/6: Publish Realex Package (NuGet Pack) (2s)
[16:23:36]  [Step 3/6] Cleaning output directory C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\Package
[16:23:36]  [Step 3/6] Cleaning C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\Package
[16:23:36]  [Step 3/6] pack: Create NuGet package from src\CompanyName.Payments.Realex\CompanyName.Payments.Realex.nuspec (1s)
[16:23:36]  [pack] NuGet command: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NuGetRunner.exe C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.4.1.0\tools\NuGet.exe pack C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\src\CompanyName.Payments.Realex\CompanyName.Payments.Realex.nuspec -OutputDirectory C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\Package -Version 1.0.64 -Properties Configuration=Release
[16:23:36]  [pack] Starting: C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script4808677879863245309.cmd
[16:23:36]  [pack] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\src\CompanyName.Payments.Realex
[16:23:36]  [pack] JetBrains TeamCity NuGet Runner 2018.1.3580.0
[16:23:36]  [pack] Registered additional extensions from paths: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\plugins-4.0
[16:23:36]  [pack] Starting NuGet.exe 4.1.0.2450 from C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.4.1.0\tools\NuGet.exe
[16:23:37]  [pack] Attempting to build package from 'CompanyName.Payments.Realex.nuspec'.
[16:23:37]  [pack] Successfully created package 'C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\Package\CompanyName.Payments.Realex.1.0.64.nupkg'.
[16:23:37]  [pack] WARNING: Issue found with package 'CompanyName.Payments.Realex'.
[16:23:37]  [pack] 
[16:23:37]  [pack] WARNING: Issue: Assembly outside lib folder.
[16:23:37]  [pack] WARNING: Description: The assembly 'lib/net45\CompanyName.Payments.Realex.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as reference when the package is installed into a project.
[16:23:37]  [pack] WARNING: Solution: Move it into the 'lib' folder if it should be referenced.
[16:23:37]  [pack] 
[16:23:37]  [pack] 
[16:23:37]  [pack] Process exited with code 0
[16:23:37]  [Step 3/6] Uploading created packages to build artifacts: CompanyName.Payments.Realex.1.0.64.nupkg
[16:23:37]  [Step 3/6] Publishing artifacts
[16:23:37]  [Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\Package\CompanyName.Payments.Realex.1.0.64.nupkg => .]
[16:23:37]  [Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]: Package/CompanyName.Payments.Realex.1.0.64.nupkg
[16:23:37]  [Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]: Package/CompanyName.Payments.Realex.1.0.64.nupkg
[16:23:38]  Step 4/6: Publish Core Package (NuGet Pack) (1s)
[16:23:38]  [Step 4/6] Cleaning output directory C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\Package
[16:23:38]  [Step 4/6] Cleaning C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\Package
[16:23:38]  [Step 4/6] pack: Create NuGet package from src\CompanyName.Payments.Core\CompanyName.Payments.Core.nuspec (1s)
[16:23:38]  [pack] NuGet command: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NuGetRunner.exe C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.4.1.0\tools\NuGet.exe pack C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\src\CompanyName.Payments.Core\CompanyName.Payments.Core.nuspec -OutputDirectory C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\Package -Version 1.0.64 -Properties Configuration=Release
[16:23:38]  [pack] Starting: C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script8506009554571830270.cmd
[16:23:38]  [pack] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\src\CompanyName.Payments.Core
[16:23:38]  [pack] JetBrains TeamCity NuGet Runner 2018.1.3580.0
[16:23:38]  [pack] Registered additional extensions from paths: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\plugins-4.0
[16:23:38]  [pack] Starting NuGet.exe 4.1.0.2450 from C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.4.1.0\tools\NuGet.exe
[16:23:39]  [pack] Attempting to build package from 'CompanyName.Payments.Core.nuspec'.
[16:23:39]  [pack] Successfully created package 'C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\Package\CompanyName.Payments.Core.1.0.64.nupkg'.
[16:23:39]  [pack] WARNING: Issue found with package 'CompanyName.Payments.Core'.
[16:23:39]  [pack] 
[16:23:39]  [pack] WARNING: Issue: Assembly outside lib folder.
[16:23:39]  [pack] WARNING: Description: The assembly 'lib/net45\CompanyName.Payments.Core.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as reference when the package is installed into a project.
[16:23:39]  [pack] WARNING: Solution: Move it into the 'lib' folder if it should be referenced.
[16:23:39]  [pack] 
[16:23:39]  [pack] 
[16:23:39]  [pack] Process exited with code 0
[16:23:39]  [Step 4/6] Uploading created packages to build artifacts: CompanyName.Payments.Core.1.0.64.nupkg
[16:23:39]  [Step 4/6] Publishing artifacts
[16:23:39]  [Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [C:\BuildAgent\work\630c5944eee6eedd\Package\CompanyName.Payments.Core.1.0.64.nupkg => .]
[16:23:39]  [Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]: Package/CompanyName.Payments.Core.1.0.64.nupkg
[16:23:39]  [Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]: Package/CompanyName.Payments.Core.1.0.64.nupkg
[16:23:39]  Step 5/6: Publish GoCardless Package (NuGet Pack) (1s)
[16:23:41]  Step 6/6: Publish DirectDebitLogic (NuGet Pack) (1s)
[16:23:43]  Publishing artifacts
[16:23:43]  [Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\nuget8440844446908059256packages\nuget.xml => .teamcity/nuget]
[16:23:43]  [Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]: C:/BuildAgent/temp/buildTmp/nuget8440844446908059256packages/nuget.xml => .teamcity/nuget
[16:23:43]  [Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]: C:/BuildAgent/temp/buildTmp/nuget8440844446908059256packages/nuget.xml => .teamcity/nuget
[16:23:43]  Publishing internal artifacts
[16:23:43]  [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[16:23:43]  [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
[16:23:44]  Build finished
```

When I looked at the build log for the successful build, it looked exactly the same.

Note: Not sure why it's warning about the the dll not being inside the 'lib' folder, because it's in lib\net45\, and the dll does get referenced when the package is installed.

Any ideas why TeamCity might suddenly only publish the one package rather than all four?

We're using TeamCity Professional 2018.1 (build 58245)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seeing the same issues since 2018.1 (build 58245). I have spent ages investigating as to why my build were misbehaving.

For now I have had do condense all separate Pack steps into one.

The other workaround is to deselect the 'Publish created packages to build artifacts' tick box for each Pack step and then put all the publishing rules into the General Settings' 'Artifact paths' like so:

[publish output directory]/[my package].nupkg
[publish output directory]/[my other package].nupkg

Hope this helps in the meantime until a fix is available.

Comment: This issue should be fixed in the next update 2018.1.1, in the meantime a quick fixed should be available from an attachment to issue TW-55703 @ 
 youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/

Comment: Yes so originally I had two 'NuGet Pack' steps each specifying an individual nuspec file. By condensing I simply listed all the  nuspec files in the 'Specification files' within a single build step and disabled the other build steps as a temporary measure.

Comment: I have also found out that publishing via General Settings does not work if you specify wildcards :(

E.g. 

[publish output directory]/*.nupkg

results in 3 out of 35 packages not being 'published'

Comment: Condensing the nuget pack steps into a single step worked for me!  Obviously this is still an issue for those that'll want separate step though.

Comment: I can confirm that the temporary fix from TW-55703 has sorted out all my issues after 'uncondensing' all of my previous changes :)